# pyparsing: match words on same line

Tags: whitespace, pyparsing

In pyparsing I'm looking for a simple way to match words (or other expressions) that occur on the same line, i.e. without any newline in between them.

Comment: You don't have to make pyparsing do all the work. If you are just parsing line by line, use `str.splitlines()` to break up into separate lines, and then pyparse them separately.

Comment: @PaulMcG I am doing something similar and will try this approach instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default whitespace-skipping characters for a particular parser element - in this case, the `word_on_the_same_line` only skips spaces, but not newlines.

```
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums)

# define special whitespace skipping, so that newlines aren't 
# skipped when matching a word_on_the_same_line
word_on_the_same_line = word().setWhitespaceChars(" ")

# compare results with this version of word_on_the_same_line to see 
# how pyparsing treats newlines as skippable whitespace
# word_on_the_same_line = word()

line = pp.Group(word("key") + word_on_the_same_line[...]("values"))

test = """\
key1 lsdkjf lskdjf lskjdf sldkjf
key2 sdlkjf lskdj lkjss lsdj
"""

print(line[...].parseString(test).dump())
```

Prints:

```
[['key1', 'lsdkjf', 'lskdjf', 'lskjdf', 'sldkjf'], ['key2', 'sdlkjf', 'lskdj', 'lkjss', 'lsdj']]
[0]:
  ['key1', 'lsdkjf', 'lskdjf', 'lskjdf', 'sldkjf']
  - key: 'key1'
  - values: ['lsdkjf', 'lskdjf', 'lskjdf', 'sldkjf']
[1]:
  ['key2', 'sdlkjf', 'lskdj', 'lkjss', 'lsdj']
  - key: 'key2'
  - values: ['sdlkjf', 'lskdj', 'lkjss', 'lsdj']
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit puzzled though why the `setWhitespaceChars` is set on `word`. I would expect it to be on `line`, since the intention is to use different whitespace chars while parsing a line, and not inside a word...

Comment: The whitespace characters you attach to a pyparsing parser element describe what characters should be skipped over _before_ trying to match that element. If you did this on line, then it would only affect whitespace skipping done before parsing the line, not the words in the line. You can also define *all* whitespace skipping to just skip spaces by calling `ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" ")`, thereby omitting any skipping of newlines. But if you do this, then you'll have to explicitly parse for `LineEnd()`s at the appropriate places in your parser.

Comment: Got it. I interpreted the word "before" (in the doc of `setWhitespaceChars`) as a temporal rather than a spatial preposition. In the documentation, you might consider using the term "leading whitespace" (instead of "whitespace before") to clarify.